# Iterate over boost::shared_array

Tags: c++, boost, c++98

How would you iterate over the items in a `boost::shared_array`? Would you do a `get()` on it and use a raw pointer as the iterator?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're already using boost, maybe like this:

```
#include <boost/shared_array.hpp>
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    boost::shared_array<int> arr(new int[10]());

    int* ptr = arr.get();
    for (int i : boost::make_iterator_range(ptr, ptr+10))
    {
        std::cout << i << ',';
    }
}
```

In any case, you need to do your own bookeeping of array's size.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing you'd already know the size of the array by the fact it had to be allocated before you create the `boost::shared_array`, the only way I see to iterate it is to use a normal `for` loop and then use `operator[i]` on the `boost::shared_array` to get an element.